# Seleinum like youtube + sign in

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to sign in to my youtube account and then press like button

what should I do else cause he giving input and email?

it's giving me sign-up again!!

this my code

```
from undetected_chromedriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium import webdriver 

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

 

# Undetected chromedriver options
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)   
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options) 

# Login
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//ytd-button-renderer/yt-button-shape/a').click() 

driver.find_element(By.ID, "identifierId").send_keys(".com")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "identifierNext").click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@type="password"]')))

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="password"]').send_keys("") 
driver.find_element(By.ID, "passwordNext").click()

# Like Video 
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=th5Br6OAEbg")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"movie_player")))  

like_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//yt-icon-button[@title='like this video']"))) 

# Click like
like_button.click()

driver.quit()
```

but after I get into the video URL I see I'm not signed in although it put my pass and email

trying to log in + get into video + press like button